# How to display a paragraph in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a small paragraph in a td table cell 
The problem is that the paragraph won't display unless if the td cell is flexible 
i've tried (white-space:pre , and white-space : word-wrap ) but it didn't work for  me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
 <td style="width: 150px;
             overflow: hidden;
             display: inline-block;
             white-space: word-wrap;"> 
                <div style="width :100px ; white-space: nowrap;">longparagrapgh heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey</div>
                  
         
              </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean "paragraph won't display"? Do you want it to wrap according to the width of the `td`?

Comment: Can you try `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: Why do you have the overflow hidden and why are you using white-space: nowrap;? Your question is unclear.

Comment: yes @Corné that's what i meant to say ! sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: thank you @Harsha your solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using `word-break` and `word-wrap`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 150px;
             overflow: hidden;
             display: inline-block;
             white-space: word-wrap;">
        <div style="width :100px ; white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word;">longparagrapgh heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey</div>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```